# t-test in R between individuals columns and the rest of a given dataframe

Tags: r, statistics, dataframe

This is in R. I need help taking a dataframe of basic format

```
       NAC     cOF3     APir       Pu       Tu     V2.3     mOF3     DGpf
1 6.314770 6.181188 6.708971 6.052134 6.546938 6.079848 6.640716 6.263770
2 8.825595 8.740217 9.532026 8.919598 8.776969 8.843287 8.631505 9.053732
3 5.518933 5.982044 5.632379 5.712680 5.655525 5.580141 5.750969 6.119935
4 6.063098 6.700194 6.255736 5.124315 6.133631 5.891009 6.070467 6.062815
5 8.931570 9.048621 9.258875 8.681762 8.680993 9.040971 8.785271 9.122226
6 5.694149 5.356218 5.608698 5.894171 5.629965 5.759247 5.929289 6.092337
```

and streamlining the task of taking a t-test of every column versus all the other columns combined. I also will need the p-values, which I plan to get via some variation on:

```
#t-test
test.result = mapply(t.test, select.column, other.columns)
#store p-values
p.values = stack(mapply(function(x, y) t.test(x,y)$p.value, select.column, other.columns))
```

Or would aov() be a better alternative for such an analysis?

Comment: ANOVA with a common post-hoc test (e.g., Tukey's) is better alternative as it will reduce the risk of type 1 errors

Answer (score 2):

```
sapply(names(dat), function(x) 
         sapply( names(dat), function(y) t.test(dat[[x]],dat[[y]])$statistic ))
```

Can use any of the values returned in the list from the function t.test. Could also have looped across the results of `combn(names(dat), 2)`, which would be a `choose(n,2)` matrix. (The square matrix has obvious redundant results) Obviously need a sensible adjustment for multiple testing. Could use `p.adjust`.