# computing T-test with help of apply function

Tags: r, statistics

I have a matrix :

```
>data

      A  A  A  B  B  C
gene1 1  6 11 16 21 26
gene2 2  7 12 17 22 27
gene3 3  8 13 18 23 28
gene4 4  9 14 19 24 29
gene5 5 10 15 20 25 30
```

I want to to test whether  the mean of each gene (rows) values are different between different groups for each gene or not? I want to use T-test for it. The function should take all columns belong to group `A`, take all columns belongs to group  `B`,  take all columns belongs to group `C`,... and calculate the T-test between each groups for each genes.(every groups contains several columns)
on implementation which I got from answer to my previews post is :

```
 Results <- combn(colnames(data), 2, function(x) t.test(data[,x]), simplify = FALSE)
 sapply(Results, "[", c("statistic", "p.value"))
```

but it does compute between all columns rather than between groups for every row. can somebody help me how to modify this code to calculate T test between groups like for my data ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [t-test in R between individuals columns and the rest of a given dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306913/t-test-in-r-between-individuals-columns-and-the-rest-of-a-given-dataframe)

Comment: I suppose it is a duplicate question, but @Jilber took the trouble to implement the `combn` alternative that I only mentioned in passing when I answered it.

Comment: Note that with the recent edit this question is now a possible duplicate of [grouping data with the same name and applying function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133594/grouping-data-with-the-same-name-and-applying-function).

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this can be usuful

```
> Mat <- matrix(1:20, nrow=4, dimnames=list(NULL, letters[1:5]))
> # t.test
> Results <- combn(colnames(Mat), 2, function(x) t.test(Mat[,x]), simplify = FALSE)
> names(Results) <- apply(Pairs, 2, paste0, collapse="~")
> Results  # Only the first element of the `Results` is shown
$`a~b`  # t.test applied to a and b

    One Sample t-test

data:  Mat[, x] 
t = 5.1962, df = 7, p-value = 0.001258
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 2.452175 6.547825 
sample estimates:
mean of x 
      4.5 
     ...
```

A nicer output:

```
> sapply(Results, "[", c("statistic", "p.value"))
          a~b        a~c         a~d         a~e        b~c         b~d          b~e          c~d         
statistic 5.196152   4.140643    3.684723    3.439126   9.814955    6.688732     5.41871      14.43376    
p.value   0.00125832 0.004345666 0.007810816 0.01085005 2.41943e-05 0.0002803283 0.0009884764 1.825796e-06
          c~e          d~e         
statistic 9.23682      19.05256    
p.value   3.601564e-05 2.730801e-07
```

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful, but i want to apply T-test for the columns which belongs to different groups. like columns 1:10 is group A and columns 11:15 group B and columns 16:20 belongs to group C. basically I want to compute the T-test between these groups. how can I modify the code to do this ?

Comment: "Pairs" not defined, but it's `combn(colnames(Mat),2)`

Answer (score 0):

almost there, with apply, you don't give arguments inside functions, but outside

```
data<-matrix(1:20,4,5)
Tscore<- apply(data, 2, t.test, alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"),mu = 0, paired = FALSE, var.equal = FALSE,conf.level = 0.95)
```

and to test if this is what you wanted, check  t stats

```
t.test(data[,1], alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"),mu = 0, paired = FALSE, var.equal = FALSE,conf.level = 0.95)
```

I may have misunderstood the question though, I just implemented your y=NULL, t test of single column